# why malloc yields error after long argv arguments?

Tags: c, malloc

I have written a program where it reads some filenames and a word from command line arguments. The first argument will be a word and remaining will be filenames. It fills a structure that I have defined.
However for small arguments, the program works correctly but for large ones `malloc` gives corrupted top size error.

Below is just initial code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILENAME_LIM 256
#define WORD_LIM 256

struct data {
    char filename[FILENAME_LIM];
    char word[WORD_LIM];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("usage: ./a.out word filename1 filename2 filename3 filename4 filename5 ...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    char word[WORD_LIM];
    strcpy(word, argv[1]);
    int files = argc - 2;
    struct data *dataarray = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(sizeof(struct data) * files));
    if (!(dataarray)) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < files; i++) {
        strcpy(dataarray[i].filename, argv[i + 2]);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < strlen(dataarray[i].filename) + 1; ii++) {
            printf("filename[%d] = %c (%d), argv[%d] = %d\n",
                   i, dataarray[i].filename[ii], dataarray[i].filename[ii],
                   i, argv[i + 2][ii]);
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I tried everything, but when I give some large filename in `argv` such as `"../../../C Programs/chess.c"`, `malloc` yields an error. I want to know what is making corrupted top size.

Comment: Whats the double sizeof in your malloc call doing? Remove the outer one.

Comment: `(struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data) * files)`

Comment: And that is not an error, but `ii < strlen(dataarray[i].filename) + 1` is the same as `ii <= strlen(dataarray[i].filename)`

Comment: What correlation is there between count of files, i.e. the value of your `files` variable, and the size of  `struct data`?  shouldn't the actual size of the file in bytes be part of this memory allocation?

Comment: [don't cast return of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).  Chage this: `struct data *dataarray = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(sizeof(struct data) * files));` to this: `struct data *dataarray = malloc(sizeof(*dataarray) * files);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sizeof(struct data) * files
```

is a valid size.  Any multiple of a size is a size.

```
sizeof(sizeof(struct data) * files)
```

is like saying `sizeof(23422)`.  I don't know what that means, and odds are the runtime isn't behaving properly either.

Restrict your use  of `sizeof(...)` to processing type arguments.

Comment: `sizeof(expr)` is exactly the same as applying `sizeof` to the type of the expression. In the case of `sizeof(23422)`, that would be the same as `typeof(int)` (probably 4), but the value of `sizeof` has type `size_t`, which is usually wider than an `int`.  So `sizeof(sizeof(struct data) * files)` is most likely 8.

Comment: It's usually better to use `sizeof(expr)` (in this case `malloc(sizeof(*dataarray) * files)`) without a cast. That protects you against using the wrong type for the object you are allocating.

Comment: @rici When one needs to explain what is happening instead of what you want, most of the "readability" battle is lost.

Comment: @edwin: i disagree: everything requires an explanation once. Is `a ^ b` not usable because someone not familiar with C might not know that `^` means xor and not power? For that matter, the difference between `sizeof` and `strlen` is apparently in constant need of explanation, as is the fact that `sizeof` is completely expanded at compile time unless its argument is a VLA.

Comment: @rici I agree that explanations are necessary.  But I have a computer that explains my code through execution, for which I can write unit tests, which never deviate from the computer's explanation while my (or other's) mental models can.  I'm glad you explained it, but as I mentioned above, I'm stating that such code should never go into production because it requires so much explanation when a more intentional writing approach (within the C code) is possible.   Cheers.

Comment: @edwin: you're entitled to your opinion, of course, but there are many people more expert than me who recommend the code I suggested, perhaps enough to call it the prevailing wisdom. See rykker's comment to the main post, for example. Or [this frequently cited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605856/1566221) . You'll also find this idiom recommended by various style guides (random example: https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece264/16au/code_quality#sizeof_argument).

Comment: @rici Please listen to the people that are more expert than you.  I've been programming C since 1985, and I've never seen a document that indicates `sizeof(...)` is supposed to take a value.  It takes a type.  The reason it doesn't crash is due to implicit promotion of a value to a type, which is not what is wanted in most cases, and certainly not what is wanted here.  If you can find a compelling use case of `sizeof(...)` taking a value that is then promoted to a type, then put it as an answer to a different question, because again it doesn't apply here.